# RightBarButtonItems won't be shown anymore on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The function `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cartBarButton` won't show my item on the right of UINavigationController's `NavBar`

**EDIT**

```
let cartOriginalImage = UIImage.cart
        let cartButton = UIImageButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        cartButton.setBackgroundImage(cartOriginalImage, for: .normal)
        cartButton.tintColor = Colors.Navigation.Tint.default
        cartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.cartButtonPressedInHomePage(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        let cartBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cartButton)

        if let badge = badge {
            cartBarButton.badgeValue = badge
            cartBarButton.badge.backgroundColor = Colors.Navigation.Background.badge
            cartBarButton.badge.textColor = Colors.Navigation.Text.badge
        }
```

Comment: Show the code which creates `cartBarButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue with custom image view. My suggestion is to wrap your custom view into container view.

```
private func configureUserAvatarView() {
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(avatarViewAction(_:)))
    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    customView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    let imageView = FUIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avatar_default_30х30"))
    imageView.isCircular = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = customView.bounds

    customView.addSubview(imageView)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
}
```

Comment: Yap - this a "live" function from my project.

Comment: You're welcome! And ... nothing strange :) In iOS 10+ your bar button item is a subview of navigation bar view. In iOS 11 - is a subview of _UIButtonBarStackView which is a subview of _UINavigationBarContentView which is subview of ... okay Apple - just take a simple UIView and do what you should do ......